# ansible : how to pass multiple commands

Tags: module, command, ansible

I tried this:

```yaml
- command: ./configure chdir=/src/package/
- command: /usr/bin/make chdir=/src/package/
- command: /usr/bin/make install chdir=/src/package/
```

which works, but I was hoping for something neater.

So I tried this:

from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043561/multiple-commands-in-the-same-line-for-bruker-topspin which give me back "no such file or directory"

```yaml
- command: ./configure;/usr/bin/make;/usr/bin/make install chdir=/src/package/
```

I tried this too: https://u.osu.edu/hasnan.1/2013/12/16/ansible-run-multiple-commands-using-command-module-and-with-items/

but I couldn't find the right syntax to put:

```yaml
- command: "{{ item }}" chdir=/src/package/
  with_items:
      ./configure
      /usr/bin/make
      /usr/bin/make install
```

That does not work, saying there is a quote issue.

Comment: I used the shell module with semi-colons as separator which worked: shell: echo "a"; echo "b"

Answer (score 130, accepted):

If a value in YAML begins with a curly brace (`{`), the YAML parser assumes that it is [a dictionary](http://docs.ansible.com/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-syntax). So, for cases like this where there is a (Jinja2) variable in the value, one of the following two strategies needs to be adopted to avoiding confusing the YAML parser:

Quote the whole command:

```yaml
- command: "{{ item }} chdir=/src/package/"
  with_items:
  - ./configure
  - /usr/bin/make
  - /usr/bin/make install
```

or change the order of the arguments:

```yaml
- command: chdir=/src/package/ {{ item }}
  with_items:
  - ./configure
  - /usr/bin/make
  - /usr/bin/make install
```

*Thanks for @RamondelaFuente alternative suggestion.*

Comment: You do need to quote the variables in some situations, like when they contain spaces, for example.

Comment: You need the double quotes around the entire command. The problem lies with the first character of the value being a "{" which has meaning in YAML. So it's - command: "{{ item }} chdir=/src/package/"

Comment: what if you have a variable in one of your items? ie - cp {{ base_dir }}

Comment: The safe option with any string (including ones with variables) is to simply quote the whole string: `"cp {{base_dir}}"`.

Answer (score 146):

To run multiple shell commands with ansible you can use the **shell** module with a multi-line string (note the **pipe** after `shell:`), as shown in this example:

```
  - name: Build nginx 
    shell: |
      cd nginx-1.11.13
      sudo ./configure
      sudo make
      sudo make install
```

Comment: thanks. is there a way to tell it to ignore failures and continue with subsequent commands in the list?

Answer (score 13):

Shell works for me.

Simply to say, Shell is the same as you run a shell script.

**Notes:**

1. Make sure use **|** when running multiple cmds.
2. Shell won't return errors if the last cmd is success (just like normal shell)
3. Control it with exit 0/1 if you want to stop ansible when error occurs.

The following example shows an error in shell, but it's success at the end of the execution.

```
- name: test shell with an error
become: no
shell: |
  rm -f /test1  # This should be an error.
  echo "test2"
  echo "test1"
  echo "test3" # success
```

This example shows stopinng shell with exit 1 error.

```
- name: test shell with exit 1
become: no
shell: |
  rm -f /test1  # This should be an error.
  echo "test2"
  exit 1        # this stops ansible due to returning an error
  echo "test1"
  echo "test3" # success
```

reference:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html

Answer (score 12):

You can also do like this:

```yaml
- command: "{{ item }}"
  args:
    chdir: "/src/package/"
  with_items:
    - "./configure"
    - "/usr/bin/make"
    - "/usr/bin/make install"
```

Hope that might help other

Answer (score 7):

Here is worker like this. \o/

```yaml
- name: "Exec items"
  shell: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - echo "hello"
    - echo "hello2"
```

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue. In my case, part of my variables were in a dictionary i.e. with_dict variable (looping) and I had to run 3 commands on each item.key. This solution is more relevant where you have to use with_dict dictionary with running multiple commands (**without requiring with_items**)

Using with_dict and with_items in one task didn't help as it was not resolving the variables.

My task was like:

```yaml
- name: Make install git source
  command: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - cd {{ tools_dir }}/{{ item.value.artifact_dir }}
    - make prefix={{ tools_dir }}/{{ item.value.artifact_dir }} all
    - make prefix={{ tools_dir }}/{{ item.value.artifact_dir }} install
  with_dict: "{{ git_versions }}"
```

roles/git/defaults/main.yml was:

```yaml
---
tool: git
default_git: git_2_6_3

git_versions:
  git_2_6_3:
    git_tar_name: git-2.6.3.tar.gz
    git_tar_dir: git-2.6.3
    git_tar_url: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.6.3.tar.gz
```

The above resulted in an error similar to the following for each {{ item }} (for 3 commands as mentioned above). As you see, the values of tools_dir is not populated (tools_dir is a variable which is defined in a common role's defaults/main.yml and also item.value.git_tar_dir value was not populated/resolved).

```
failed: [server01.poc.jenkins] => (item=cd {# tools_dir #}/{# item.value.git_tar_dir #}) => {"cmd": "cd '{#' tools_dir '#}/{#' item.value.git_tar_dir '#}'", "failed": true, "item": "cd {# tools_dir #}/{# item.value.git_tar_dir #}", "rc": 2}
msg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Solution was easy. Instead of using "COMMAND" module in Ansible, I used "Shell" module and created a a variable in roles/git/defaults/main.yml

So, now roles/git/defaults/main.yml looks like:

```yaml
---
tool: git
default_git: git_2_6_3

git_versions:
  git_2_6_3:
    git_tar_name: git-2.6.3.tar.gz
    git_tar_dir: git-2.6.3
    git_tar_url: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.6.3.tar.gz

#git_pre_requisites_install_cmds: "cd {{ tools_dir }}/{{ item.value.git_tar_dir }} && make prefix={{ tools_dir }}/{{ item.value.git_tar_dir }} all && make prefix={{ tools_dir }}/{{ item.value.git_tar_dir }} install"

#or use this if you want git installation to work in ~/tools/git-x.x.x
git_pre_requisites_install_cmds: "cd {{ tools_dir }}/{{ item.value.git_tar_dir }} && make prefix=`pwd` all && make prefix=`pwd` install"

#or use this if you want git installation to use the default prefix during make 
#git_pre_requisites_install_cmds: "cd {{ tools_dir }}/{{ item.value.git_tar_dir }} && make all && make install"
```

and the task **roles/git/tasks/main.yml** looks like:

```yaml
- name: Make install from git source
  shell: "{{ git_pre_requisites_install_cmds }}"
  become_user: "{{ build_user }}"
  with_dict: "{{ git_versions }}"
  tags:
    - koba
```

This time, the values got successfully substituted as the module was "SHELL" and ansible output echoed the correct values. **This didn't require with_items:** loop.

```
"cmd": "cd ~/tools/git-2.6.3 && make prefix=/home/giga/tools/git-2.6.3 all && make prefix=/home/giga/tools/git-2.6.3 install",
```